# Unable to Launch EC2 Instances Asynchronously via Terraform

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, user-data, infrastructure-as-code

I am willing to launch two instances via Terraform. First one will generate some certificate files, push to S3 bucket. The second instance will pull those certificates from particular S3 bucket. Both operations will be handled by user data. The problem here is pull commands (aws cli) in user data of second instance are not working. (It is working when I try from shell) I think the issue is about terraform is launching both instances synchronously so that second instance is getting launched before first instance pushes the certificates to S3.

I also tried to handle this by adding "depends_on" to my code but it did not work. I am looking for a way to launch the instances asynchronously. Like second instance will be launched after 30 seconds then first instance is launched. Here I am pasting the related part of the code.

```
data "template_file" "first_executor" {
  template = file("some_path/first_executor.sh")
}

resource "aws_instance" "first_instance" {
  ami = data.aws_ami.amazon-linux-2.id
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  user_data = data.template_file.first_executor.rendered
  network_interface {
    device_index = 0
    network_interface_id = aws_network_interface.first_instance-network-interface.id
  }
}

###

data "template_file" "second_executor" {
  template = file("some_path/second_executor.sh")
}

resource "aws_instance" "second_instance" {
  depends_on = [aws_instance.first_instance]
  ami = data.aws_ami.amazon-linux-2.id
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  user_data = data.template_file.second_executor.rendered
  network_interface {
    device_index = 0
    network_interface_id = aws_network_interface.second-network-interface.id
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer is no. "depends_on" in Terraform means it will wait for a resource to be available. This means, your second EC2 will be created as soon as first EC2 is triggered.

Terraform will not wait till your first EC2 is in "running" state or if user data is executed.

I would suggest go with depdens_on and then, in your second EC2 user data script, add some logic to have a loop which will look up S3 and will wait and repeat till the resources are found.